# No results on my "Disregard PEMDAS" Number calculator

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that, when given an expression, disregards the PEMDAS rules, and just spits out a strict left-to-right answer (e.g. 5+4*4/6 = 6). I'm SO close to finishing it, but I cannot get an output anymore. I've made changes from once I could get an output. But now It won't give me anything. Take a look at my before and after shots!
The first bit of code works, only after you press enter and give it a random int value... It needs another int value to finish the while loop i've set up. The second one doesn't work. The changes I've made are that i've set up a value ck, this checks to see if car has a value in it, aka = 1. If it doesn't then the loop is finished. Let me know what you think. And thank you so much for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  int num, total;
  char car;
  //Setting up integers and a char value

  printf("Please enter an expression to be evaluated: \n");
  scanf("%d", &total); // User prompt, grabs the first value. Stores in total.

   while(car != '\n'){

   scanf(" %c", &car);
   scanf("%d", &num);

    if(car == '*'){
    total = (total*num);
    } // Multiplies total and new number value if '*' is enterd

   else if(car == '/'){
     total = (total/num);
   } // Divides total and new number value if '/' is entered

   else if(car == '+'){
     total = (total+num);
   } // Adds total and new number value if '+' is entered

   else if(car == '-'){
     total = (total-num);
   } // Subtracts total and new number value if '-' is entered

       else if(car == '\n'){
       printf("%d\n", total):
   }    
 }
}
```

==========================================================================================

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  int num, total;
  char car;
  int ck = 1; //Setting up integers and a char value

  printf("Please enter an expression to be evaluated: \n");
  scanf("%d", &total); // User prompt, grabs the first value. Stores in total.

   while(ck == 1 ){

   scanf(" %c", &car);
   scanf("%d", &num);

   ck = scanf(" %c", &car);
   if(ck != 1){
     printf("%d\n", total);
   }//Newest code input

    if(car == '*'){
    total = (total*num);
    } // Multiplies total and new number value if '*' is enterd

   else if(car == '/'){
     total = (total/num);
   } // Divides total and new number value if '/' is entered

   else if(car == '+'){
     total = (total+num);
   } // Adds total and new number value if '+' is entered

   else if(car == '-'){
     total = (total-num);
   } // Subtracts total and new number value if '-' is entered

    //   else if(car == '\n'){
    //   printf("%d\n", total):
    //   }
    // Old end to if statement block, gives output. But only after another int
    // is put in.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit your first code by taking `scanf("%c", &car);` out to the `while` and place it once more just before the end of `while`. Move `printf` out of `while` .This is your modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int num, total;
    char car;

    printf("Please enter an expression to be evaluated: \n");
    scanf("%d", &total); // User prompt, grabs the first value. Stores in total.
    scanf("%c", &car);
    while(car != '\n'){
        scanf("%d", &num); //Newest code input

        if(car == '*'){
            total = (total*num);
        } // Multiplies total and new number value if '*' is enterd

        else if(car == '/'){
              total = (total/num);
        } // Divides total and new number value if '/' is entered

        else if(car == '+'){
             total = (total+num);
        } // Adds total and new number value if '+' is entered

        else if(car == '-'){
             total = (total-num);
        }
        scanf("%c", &car);
    } 
    printf ("%d", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem here is that you ask for an operator (*car*) and a number (*num*) at the same time. You should first ask for *car*, then check if it is not an '\n', and then ask for the number. Here is a modification of your second version that does that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int num, total;
    char car;
    int ck = 1; //Setting up integers and a char value
    printf("Please enter an expression to be evaluated: \n");
    scanf("%d", &total); // User prompt, grabs the first value. Stores in total.
    while(ck == 1 ) {
        scanf("%c", &car);
        if (car !='\n') {
            scanf("%d", &num);

            if(car == '*') {
                total = (total*num);
            } // Multiplies total and new number value if '*' is enterd

            else if(car == '/') {
                total = (total/num);
            } // Divides total and new number value if '/' is entered

            else if(car == '+') {
                total = (total+num);
            } // Adds total and new number value if '+' is entered

            else if(car == '-') {
                total = (total-num);
            } // Subtracts total and new number value if '-' is entered
        } else {
            ck=0; //break the while loop
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
}
```

Comment: This works great! But still when I press enter (\n) it doesn't return a value until a ctrl-D in Unix.

Comment: mmm, maybe try with: if (car =='\n' && car!='\r')

Comment: instead of: if (car !='\n')
It will likely make no difference, but maybe you're getting a '\r' with Enter

Comment: Typo: try this instead
if (car !='\n' && car!='\r')

Comment: This works great! But it still only outputs when I force EOF into the program with ctrl-D, not when I just press enter